# Using Colspan in Pageblock section

Tags: visualforce

In Salesforce Visualforce page, how can I get apex:outputText to left align within a pageblocksection using colspan in an embedded table ? I can use text by itself but prefer to use the outPuttext tag. Attached pic showing the results.

[image]

```
    <apex:outputPanel Style="width:100%;" layout="block">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="LOB_AH1" title="AH" showHeader="false" >

       <tr>
       <td colspan="4" style="text-align:left;">
           * Account Underwriting Summary Analysis and Decision
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td colspan="4" style="text-align:left;">
           <apex:outputText value="** Account Underwriting Summary Analysis and Decision"  />
       </td>      
       </tr>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualforce will cause `apex:` prefixed elements to try and get in to their proper places, using a number of table columns times two as specified on the page block section (so, columns="2" results in 4 table columns).

Your best bet is to use an apex:pageBlockSectionItem to align everything to natural page block section items. You'll probably need to add an extra (blank) item to get the next line to start in the correct spot.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="LOB_AH1" title="AH" showHeader="false" >
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      <apex:outputText value="** Account Underwriting Summary Analysis and Decision"  />
  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```